# Sydney, Australia - for 5 days. With a 6-month old baby. Any tips?

Tags: accommodation, australia, food-and-drink, children, sydney

My wife and I are living in San Francisco, CA (SFO) and are going to Sydney, Australia (SYD) for a short trip (5 days), probably in October or November.  I will be attending a training for only 1 day out of the 5 days.

We have a 6-month old baby, that is still breastfed and has not started eating solid food yet.

Unlike most people here, we are not "professional" traveler, and have not ventured over 40 miles radius of our house in the past 6 months. In the past 3 years, we have only been abroad twice (Italy and Hongkong).

Given that we have a 6-month old :

- What's your recommendation on a good hotel or apartment, or a good area to be in? Main factors: easy to find food, not much pollution/car traffic, pedestrian-friendly (maybe with pedestrian-only squares like Europe), family friendly, safe.
- Is apartment-style hotel better, since we can potentially cook simple food?
- Is there an all-inclusive resort around Sydney, or should we book "Club-Level" Room for easy access to food?
- What's the best, most effective way, cost efficient way to get food or water?
- Should we bring a stroller? What stroller would you recommend?
- Should we use baby carrier? I regularly use Baby Bjorn Comfort Carrier to take my baby for a walk.
- Any other tips or suggestions?

Comment: I think this question would be better as two or three seperate questions.

Answer (score 5):

My first suggestion would be to find a serviced apartment near [Darling Harbour](http://www.darlingharbour.com/).  You do not mention budget, but this would probably cost around 200 AUD / night.

A serviced apartment will have a microwave, fridge, and stove, etc.  You can walk to nearby [Coles or Woolworths supermarkets](https://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=supermarket%20near%20darling%20harbour%20sydney&hl=en&ll=-33.871164,151.198525&spn=0.029931,0.066047&sll=-33.87291,151.210756&sspn=0.029931,0.066047&t=h&gl=au&hq=supermarket&hnear=Darling%20Harbour,%20Sydney%20New%20South%20Wales%202000&z=15) and buy food to cook meals yourself.  There are also many restaraunts nearby.  I would go for one on the Eastern side of the harbour so as to be closer to the city.

This is a safe area.  There would be some drunken idiots walking between nightclubs and pubs late on a Friday or Saturday night but you are not likely to be out at that time anyway.  During the day it is full of families and office workers.

From Darling Harbour there are nearby family-friendly attractions, and you can always return to the apartment in the middle of the day easily.  If you decide to go further you could catch a train from Town Hall or Wynyard Station to Circular Quay and then a ferry across to Manly or Toranga Zoo.  I would not hire a car unless you intend to venture right out of Sydney.